# Is it practically possible to replace deformed mirror segments after impact in a service mission?

Tags: james-webb-telescope

After reading the first articles about Webb being hit by micrometeorites/ dust and that this was more than expected, I was wondering whether it would be possible to have a service mission to replace one of the mirrors if later required.

As to my knowledge no service missions at all are planned, I am aware that there is no plan but I would be curious whether it is technically feasible at all.

The stuff replaced in Hubble was to my knowledge all rigid and the mirrors of Webb are very thin and probably much more fragile.

Comment: Relevant https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57355/if-we-can-get-people-to-the-moon-and-back-why-are-we-so-adamant-that-its-impos

Comment: Anything is feasible if you throw enough money at it.